# How to solve "not found:(NXDOMAIN)

Tags: 18.04, server, active-directory, domain-server, samba4

I install Samba in ubuntu 18.04 showing. After install samba, I test the installation
by #samba-tool domain level show:(it give me the result)
**Domain and forest function level for domain 'DC=nassa, DC=local'**
in etc/resolv.conf nameserver 8.8.8.8
if i write 127.0.0.1 then internet become disconnected.

after the command #host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.nassa.local.
showing "Host _ldap._tcp.nassa.local. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)"

Answer (score 0):

The hostname nassa.local seems to indicate that you are using avahi. Make sure avahi-daemon is up and running on all involved hosts (e.g. `ping nassa.local` should work)

Comment: hi Arved I am trying to install samba active directory in ubuntu 18.04. during the installation it was successful and that time I set domain "nassa.local" in this. during this process i didnt use Avahi.

Comment: well you did not set the domain correct, otherwise it would be resolveable. Avahi is one solution, if you want to run your own DNS infrastructure